# Python - Create dataframe by getting the numbers of alphabetic characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column called "Utterances", which contains strings (e.g.: "I wanna have a beer" is its first row).

What I need is to create a new data frame that will contain the number of every letter of every row of "Utterances" in the alphabet.

This means that for example in the case of "I wanna have a beer", I need to get the following row: 9 23114141 81225 1 25518, since "I" is the 9th letter of the alphabet, "w" the 23rd and so on. Notice that I want the spaces " " to be maintained.

What I have done so far is the following:

```
for word in df2[['Utterances']]:
   for character in word:
      new.append(ord(character.lower())-96)
   str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in new)
```

The above returns the concatenated string. However, the above loop only iterates once and second the string returned by str1 does not have the required spaces (" "). And of course, I can not find a way to append these lines into a new dataframe.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
In [5572]: df
Out[5572]:
            Utterances
0  I wanna have a beer

In [5573]: df['Utterances'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([''.join(str(ord(c)-96) for c in w) 
                                             for w in x.lower().split()]))
Out[5573]:
0    9 23114141 81225 1 25518
Name: Utterances, dtype: object
```

Comment: OMG 6 mins earlier?

Answer (score 0):

```
for word in ['I ab c def']:
    for character in word:
        if character == ' ':
            new.append(' ')
        else:
            new.append(ord(character.lower())-96)
        str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in new)
```

Output

```
9 12 3 456
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets use dictionary and get with strings if you have only alphabets i.e

```
import string

dic = {j:i+1 for i,j in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase[:26])}
dic[' ']= ' '
df['Ut'].apply(lambda x : ''.join([str(dic.get(i)) for i in str(x).lower()]))
```

Output :

```
                   Ut                       new
0  I wanna have a beer  9 23114141 81225 1 25518
```

​